# Passart und Nummer In English?

Tags: meaning, translation

I cannot find the answer to this anywhere. I am filling out a residence permit renewal form.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the original form text.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please [edit] your question to specify: 1. In what contexts do these words appear? 2. What is the (English) form asking for?

Answer (score 2):

*"Passart"* would be the kind of passport you have.
*"Nummer"* is the passport number

Comment: The problem with forms is often that you don't know what the allowed or expected answers are. What kinds of passports are there?

Comment: @DavidVogt: Typically, "Reisepass", "Diplomatenpass", and maybe a few more if the German word is really "Passart". If it includes other types of ID cards, "Passart" would be a somewhat unusual term IMHO.